Conditional tick mark removal?
Can tick marks be removed where there is no label in deneb?
We also want to keep the max amount of gridlines possible.
Before

After

I tried using the conditional labels/located in the documentation, but could not get my expression to respect the labels in the chart above.

In order to help, we need a spec including data or a .pbix.

I'm not sure if I can provide the .pbix as it may contain some sensitive data, but can I provide the config code? Thanks!

Try and always post a spec with sample data so it works in vega editor. Thanks

Then create fake data that demonstrates the same problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have a sample .pbix that I can give to you all, but not sure how to attach it through Stack Overflow? How is it normally done?

Here is an example which shows a possible solution for you.
I divide value by 10 and round it to 0 decimal. If it still equals itself divided by 10 then we color tick otherwise we set it as transparent.
We don't want to change tickSize because then the values will be misaligned.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/population.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.year == 2000"},
    {"calculate": "datum.sex == 2 ? 'Female' : 'Male'", "as": "gender"}
  ],
  "height": {"step": 17},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "age",
      "axis": {
        "tickSize": 8,
        "tickColor": {
          "expr": "round((datum.value/10),0) == (datum.value/10) ? 'black':'transparent'"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "people",
          "title": "population",
          "stack": "normalize"
        },
        "color": {"field": "gender", "scale": {"range": ["#675193", "#ca8861"]}}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "opacity": 0.9, "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "people",
          "title": "population",
          "stack": "normalize",
          "bandPosition": 0.5
        },
        "text": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "people", "title": "population"},
        "detail": {"field": "gender"}
      }
    }
  ]
}


This worked thank you! I was able to use this replicate this formula using modulus and it seemed to work.
